# Data.Map: how do I tell if I "need value-strict maps"?

Tags: haskell

When choosing between `Data.Map.Lazy` and `Data.Map.Strict`, the docs tell us for the former:

> API of this module is strict in the keys, but lazy in the values. *If you need* value-strict maps, use `Data.Map.Strict` instead.

and for the latter likewise:

> API of this module is strict in both the keys and the values. *If you need* value-lazy maps, use `Data.Map.Lazy` instead.

How do more seasoned Haskellers than me tend to intuit this "need"? Use-case in point, in a run-and-done (ie. not daemon-like/long-running) command-line tool: `readFile`ing a simple `lines`-based custom config file where many (not all) lines define key:value pairs to be collected into a `Map`. Once done, we rewrite many values in it depending on other values in it that were read later (thanks to immutability, in this process we create a new `Map` and discard the initial incarnation).

(Although in practice this file likely won't often or ever reach even a 1000 lines, let's just assume for the sake of learning that for some users it will before long.)

Any given run of the tool will perhaps lookup some 20-100% of the (rewritten on load, although with lazy-eval I'm never quite sure "when *really*") key:value pairs, anywhere between once and dozens of times.

How do I reason about the differences between "value-strict" and "value-lazy" `Data.Map`s here? What happens "under the hood", in terms of mainstream computing if you will?

Fundamentally, such hash-maps are of course about "storing once, looking up many times" --- but then, what in computing isn't, "fundamentally". And furthermore the whole concept of lazy-eval's thunks seems to boil down to this very principle, so why not *always* stay value-lazy?

Comment: Did you miss the [note at the top of `Data.Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.9.1/docs/Data-Map.html)?

Comment: Thanks. Not sufficiently explicit to really conclude anything in a real case for me:

"..You will eventually need all the values stored.", what in memory, serialized on disk for a temp duration, or 10 years, or derivatives of it stored some-place for some-time? Of course the output of the program will directly or indirectly persist in some fashion. Depending on the usage of it, not all of the values will have to be "stored" verbatim. So should I prefer Lazy then? Or doesn't-matter-it now?...

Comment: "The stored values don't represent large virtual data structures to be lazily computed." --- how large is large? Are "small virtual data structures to be lazily computed" a different matter? Etc.....  ;) ERGO: would be better if I had the exact facts at hand to be able to reason myself about both options for each hands-on use-case --- and those suggestions you pointed to (and I had seen earlier) don't volunteer such knowledge

Comment: Those are rule of thumbs. The definitive answer is: profile your code. :)

Comment: Sure. One of course makes the best choice only when knowing EXACTLY the implementation details. Either by writing the package in question, or reading its sources thoroughly (plus gained hard-won real-world experiences), or as in my case by asking more seasoned practitioners on here if they too like to operate on a foundation of all-out in-depth understanding instead of just advertised heuristics-of-thumb and thusly put in said efforts already PLUS happen to happen across the question PLUS choose to spend their time explaining the actual practical differences to the wider audience here ;))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do I reason about the differences between "value-strict" and "value-lazy" Data.Maps here?

Value lazy is the normal in Haskell. This means that not just values, but thunks (i.e. recipes of how to compute the value) are stored. For example, lets say you extract the value from a line like this:

```
tail (dropUntil (==':') line)
```

Then a value-strict map would actually extract the value upon insert, while a lazy one would happily just remember how to get it. This is then also what you would get on a `lookup`

Here are some pros and cons:

- lazy values may need more memory, not only for the thunk itself, but also for the data that are referenced there (here `line`).
- strict values may need more memory. In our case this could be so when the string gets interpreted to yield some memory hungry structure like lists, JSON or XML.
- using lazy values may need less CPU if your code doesn't need every value.
- too deep nesting of thunks may cause stack-overflows when the value is finally needed.
- there is also a semantic difference: in lazy mode, you may get away when the code to extract the value would fail (like the above one that fails if there isnt a ':' on the line) if you just need to look whether the key is present. In strict mode, your program crashes upon insert.

As always, there are no fixed measures like: "If your evaluated value needs less than 20 bytes and takes less than 30µs to compute, use strict, else use lazy."

Normally, you just go with one and when you notice extreme runtimes/memory usage you try the other.

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly the kind of reasoning I was hoping to be able to develop over time! Thanks, much appreciated.

I assume the lazy goes back all the way to the original `lines` split of the `readFile`? Well this I can now easily go grasp from the docs again I guess.. cheers!

Comment: Wrt the semantic difference, a key point to me, is that a lazy map can be self referential: `let m = M.fromList [ ('a', 1), ('b', (m Map.! 'a')+1) ]` which lets you do fancy neat things that are impossible with strict maps

Answer (score 3):

Here's a small experiment that shows a difference betwen `Data.Map.Lazy` and `Data.Map.Strict`. This code exhausts the heap:

```
import Data.Foldable
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as M

main :: IO ()
main = print $ foldl' (\kv i -> M.adjust (+i) 'a' kv) 
                      (M.fromList [('a',0)])
                      (cycle [0])
```

(Better to compile with a small maximum heap, like `ghc Main.hs -with-rtsopts="-M20m"`.)

The `foldl'` keeps the map in WHNF as we iterate over the infinite list of zeros. However, thunks accumulate in the modified value until the heap is exhausted.

The same code with `Data.Map.Strict` simply loops forever. In the strict variant, the values are in WHNF whenever the map is in WHNF.

Comment: Indeed, lazy `adjust` is almost never what you want anywhere. Lazy `insert` is fine though.